# Insert multiple records from query when only part of each record comes from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

I have a table that adds customers to a user, `UserCustomerXRef`.

| Username | Link | Deleted | Last_Modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jsmith | 10001 | N | 2023-01-12 17:02:25.857 |
| Jsmith | 10003 | Y | 2022-12-13 05:03:47.923 |

I want to add multiple records to this table, attaching multiple customerIDs to a single username.

To get this list of customers I would use a select command like

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM Customers 
WHERE Country = 'US'
```

This returns a list of 200 rows.

I know how to create a single record using values like

```
INSERT INTO UserCustomerXRef 
VALUES ('Rroe', '10001', GetDate(), 'N')
```

I know how to create a subset of a table with multiple records by selecting columns from another table.

```
INSERT INTO CustomersUS 
    SELECT (CustomerID, Name, Address1, City) 
    FROM Customers 
    WHERE Country = 'US'
```

What I don't know how to do is the create a query from both, where I supply the 'Rroe', 'N', and GetDate() values, and the CustomerID comes from the `Customers` table.

What I usually do is this:

```
SELECT ('(' + CHAR(39) + 'Rroe' + CHAR(39) + ', ' + CHAR(39) + CustomerID 
+ CHAR(39) + ', GetDate(), ' + CHAR(39) + 'N' + CHAR(39) + '),') 
FROM Customers 
WHERE Country = 'US'
```

This returns an output like

```
('Rroe  ', '900001', GetDate(), 'N'),
('Rroe  ', '900019', GetDate(), 'N'),
('Rroe  ', '900027', GetDate(), 'N'),
('Rroe  ', '900035', GetDate(), 'N'),
('Rroe  ', '900043', GetDate(), 'N'),
('Rroe  ', '900050', GetDate(), 'N'),
('Rroe  ', '900068', GetDate(), 'N'),
('Rroe  ', '900076', GetDate(), 'N'),
('Rroe  ', '900092', GetDate(), 'N'),
('Rroe  ', '900100', GetDate(), 'N'),
('Rroe  ', '900118', GetDate(), 'N'),
```

I copy this to the query window, type

```
INSERT INTO UserCustomerXRef 
VALUES
```

above it, delete the comma after the last line, and run it.

This works, but surely there's a query that will do like.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO UserCustomerXRef 
VALUES ('Rroe', SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers, GetDate(), 'N') 
WHERE Customers.Country = 'US"
```

Comment: it should be something like ```INSERT INTO UserCustomerXRef Select 'Rroe', CustomerID, GetDate(), 'N' from Customers where Customers.Country = 'US'```

Answer (score 2):

Although you put some effort in your question it is hard to understand what you really want to achieve. I think you are just looking for the correct syntax to insert a mixture of "static" data and data based on a query.

```
INSERT INTO UserCustomerXRef 
(
    Username,
    Link,
    Deleted,
    Last_Modified
) 
SELECT 
    'Rroe', 
    C.CustomerID, 
    'N',
    GETDATE()
) 
FROM Customers C
WHERE C.Country = 'US';
```

Comment: Yup, exactly what I was trying to do...and something I had apparently figured out 18 months ago and forgot I knew.  Thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was poking around and found I had already created an answer in our company SQL library.

```
INSERT INTO UserCustomerXRef 
SELECT 'Rroe', CustomerID, GetDate(), 'N'
FROM Customers WHERE Deleted = 'N'
AND Country = 'US'
```